# camera_based localization

Tags: localization, navigation, kinect, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
I'm on this localization project and I'm required to do localization using a kinect camera. I did some research and all the resources I found are using laser scan instead of a camera, like the ACML package. So I'm wondering if anyone knows a good resource on camera_based localization. Lots of thanks !!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40670/camera_based-localization/) by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can take a look at [rgbdslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) package

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on 2012-12-02**:
thanks yay that's what I tried using but it's much nosier than laser scanner so in the end I just used laser scanner. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did also see a technique somewhere (cannot tell where any more unfortunately) where they just took a slice of their kinect data to get the same data as a laser scanner. So that you can use the kinect as if it where a laser scanner.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-11-24**:
I think the package your thinking of is pointcloud_to_laserscan from the turtlebot stack. http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you may have to use VSLAM which refer to Visual Simultaneous Localization and Mapping
but this require feedback from vision system and odometer system

most simplified one using only Vision system is by using Bearing Only SLAM

---

Originally posted by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) with karma: 229 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-24**:
sry I do not know if it is supported in ROS but I use these techniques in Autonomous Mine Sweeper Project